# join columns recursively in R

Tags: r

Hello I have a data frame of 245 columns but to add some sets and generate new columns try to do it recursively as follows

```
cl1<-sample(1:4,10,replace=TRUE)
cl2<-sample(1:4,10,replace=TRUE)
cl3<-sample(1:4,10,replace=TRUE)
cl4<-sample(1:4,10,replace=TRUE)
cl5<-sample(1:4,10,replace=TRUE)
cl6<-sample(1:4,10,replace=TRUE)
dat<-data.frame(cl1,cl2,cl3,cl4,cl5,cl6)
```

my intention is to add column 1 with column 3 and 5, likewise column 2 with 4 and 6 and in the end obtain a dataframe with two columns

[image]

and you should pay me something like that[image]

I have programmed the following code

```
revisar<- function(a){
  todos = list()
  i=1
  j=3
  l=5
  k=1
  while(i<=2 ){
    
    cl<-a[,i]
    cl2<-a[,j]
    cl3<-a[,l]
    cl[is.na(cl)] <- 0
    cl2[is.na(cl2)] <- 0
    cl3[is.na(cl3)] <- 0
    
    colu<-cl+cl2+cl3
    
    col<-cbind(colu,colu)
    
    i<-i+1
    j<-j+1
    l<-l+1
    k<-k+1
  }
 
  return(col)
}
```

it turns out that it only returns column 2 repeated twice and I must replicate the same thing to join those 245 columns.7

I would like to know what is failing the example

Comment: Try `dat %>% mutate(s1 = rowSums(across(c(cl1, cl3, cl5))), s2 = rowSums(across(c(cl2, cl4, cl6))))`

Answer (score 4):

### base R

Literal programming:

```r
with(dat, data.frame(s1 = cl1+cl3+cl5, s2 = cl2+cl4+cl6))
#    s1 s2
# 1   7 11
# 2   7  7
# 3   4 11
# 4   4 10
# 5   9  8
# 6  12  5
# 7   7  6
# 8   7 10
# 9   4  9
# 10  6  5
```

Programmatically,

```r
L <- list(s1 = c(1,3,5), s2 = c(2,4,6))
out <- data.frame(lapply(L, function(z) do.call(rowSums, list(as.matrix(dat[,z])))))
out
#    s1 s2
# 1   7 11
# 2   7  7
# 3   4 11
# 4   4 10
# 5   9  8
# 6  12  5
# 7   7  6
# 8   7 10
# 9   4  9
# 10  6  5
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  transmute(
    s1 = rowSums(cbind(cl1, cl3, cl5)),
    s2 = rowSums(cbind(cl2, cl4, cl6))
  )
```

or programmatically using `purrr`:

```r
purrr::map_dfc(L, ~ rowSums(dat[, .]))
```

---

Data

```r
set.seed(42)
# your `dat` above
```

Comment: thanks i did it with my original base
```
L <- list(s1 = c(8:35), s2 = c(82:116), s3=c(160:194) )
out <- data.frame(lapply(L, function(z) do.call(rowSums, list(as.matrix(weather[,z])))))
out
```
but it gives me the following error    "Error in (function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1L) : 'x' must be numeric"

Comment: I think that's pretty clear, one or more of your columns are not numeric. The fact that you're seeing that suggests something is missing earlier in your data import, whether it be mis-placed `colClasses=` or corrupted data. I suggest changing`list(as.matrix(weather[,z]))` to `list(sapply(weather[,z], as.numeric))`. I'm going to guess you'll see warnings about `NAs introduced by coercion`. You should verify these columns are all numeric as you are assuming.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative general approach:

Here we sum all uneven columns -> s1 and
all even columns -> s2:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(s1 = sum(c_across(seq(1,ncol(dat),2)), na.rm = TRUE),
         s2 = sum(c_across(seq(2,ncol(dat),2)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
     cl1   cl2   cl3   cl4   cl5   cl6    s1    s2
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1     3     2     3     2     7     5
 2     2     4     1     4     2     3     5    11
 3     2     2     2     2     1     3     5     7
 4     2     4     4     3     1     4     7    11
 5     2     4     4     3     2     2     8     9
 6     3     3     3     2     2     2     8     7
 7     2     1     1     2     1     4     4     7
 8     2     4     1     3     2     3     5    10
 9     3     1     1     2     3     4     7     7
10     2     4     1     3     4     4     7    11
```